# Setting Tkinter default widgets kwargs

Tags: python, tkinter

How do you change the default Tkinter kwargs values for certain widgets?

I know you can set a general Tkinter theme with tk_setPalette(theme) so it computes and overwrites default values and tries to use colors that best matches the new theme but I would like something with more control.

For example, let's say I want to easily change the background color of my Tkinter widgets, I'd do something like:

```
import Tkinter as tk
COLOR = 'blue' #This would be in some constant or setting modules

class CustomButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, root, **options):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, root, bg=COLOR, **options)
```

Then if at some point I want to change the background color from blue to red I'd just need to edit my setting.py module. (background is an example, I want to easily change any **kwargs)

I'm sure there's a better way to do this and something somewhere let's you set default widgets values without overriding every single widget in a wrapper class...

Comment: Dunno much about tk, but from this is seems like if you want nicely-implemented theme/styling support, you need to use `tkinter.ttk` APIs. http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ttk.html

Comment: The ttk.Style() looks to be exactly what I would need for Tk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this was asked a couple of years back, but for anyone with the same issue who stumbles upon this thread, here is an example of how to incorporate generalised settings for your widgets:

```
my_options = {"bg" : "gray60", "font" : ("Tahoma", 20)}

tk.Label(root, text = "Same background", **my_options).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
tk.Button(root, text = "and font.", **my_options).grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = (5, 0))
```

Take note that the option must but be a string, however the value is as usual (i.e. a string for colour, but an integer for height).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built-in to do this for you, but it takes just a few lines of code to implement. You can change any attribute at runtime with the config (or configure) method, so, for example, you can do something like this:

```
def resetUI(self, bg=None, fg=None):
    for button in list_of_buttons:
        button.config(background=bg, foreground=fg)
```

Comment: Yeah I thought nothing was built-in but I still wanted to be sure before trying to reinvent the wheel with an inferior homemade solution. Thanks for the snippets it gave me a lot of ideas.